# Invalidate PhpStorm's caches manually - PhpStorm getting stuck loading project

Tags: phpstorm

For some reason, PhpStorm has decided to all of a sudden get stuck at "Loading project...", which seems to be at the step of "Scanning files to index...".

No matter how long I leave it it doesn't get any further, and the window reports it is "Not Responding".

I've read a potential solution is to "Invalidate caches", but that's pretty hard to do when I can't even get the program to function.

How can I do this step manually, or is this the correct way to handle this?

I even tried creating an empty folder and opening that as a new project, but same issue.

Comment: Hi, that sucks/stucks. Better ask jetbrains, you paid for the product.
Alternatively, check your OS errorlogs maybe for hints?

Comment: You can invalidate the caches manually by removing the [system directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#system-directory) while PhpStorm is not running

Comment: @EugeneMorozov Is there anything that states this is safe to do? Is this the exact same process of invalidating it via the program itself?

Comment: @Brett 1) Content in the system directory can be discarded as it is generated from the actual project content (indexes/caches/other downloadable content). 2) Imagine getting a new computer and moving your IDE settings there -- this folder will not be copied there (no need). 3) Even more simple: upgrading from older to a newer IDE version (e.g. 2022.3 to the next 2023.1) -- once again, system folder will not be copied, only config one.

Comment: @Brett So yes, it is safe enough. If you afraid -- make a backup of the config folder (or whatever other folders) if so desired.

Comment: @Brett *"I've read a potential solution is to "Invalidate caches", but that's pretty hard to do when I can't even get the program to function."* Another approach if you insist on using "Invalidate Cache": 1) Close ALL projects (so you see the Welcome screen with the list of recent projects). 2) Invoke shortcut for `Help | Find Action...` (normally `Ctrl+Shift+A` here on Windows keymap) 3) search for "Invalidate Caches" and invoke that action this way.

Comment: @Brett May want to try `Repair IDE" first (it includes the "Invalidate caches" step as well) -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/repair-ide.html

Comment: @LazyOne Ok, I deleted all the files in the _system_ directory and reopened PhpStorm, but it still got stuck. I seen the repair page before, but since I couldn't access the menu, I couldn't do that. I am unsure how to get it to stop loading the last project when I open it unfortunately.

Comment: @LazyOne I just installed a new version (an older version, but the next version up from what I had), and it still can't get past the indexing.

Really no idea what's going on and why it did this all of a sudden. :(

Comment: @Brett In such a case (not sure what is happing and why) -- contact JetBrains Support where you can privately provide all requested info (`idea.log` file and other logs) -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731 It's hard (useless) to suggest something when you have no idea about the setup / what kind of project that is / list of plugins etc etc. Better get that info first and then get some ideas from there.